# Unable to measure static arrays memory usage with GetProcessMemoryInfo

Tags: c++, memory, profiling, ram, measure

I am trying to learn both details on memory usage works, as well as how to measure it using C++. I know that under Windows, a quick way to retrieve the amount of RAM being used by the current application process, when including `<Windows.h>`, is:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess( ), &info, sizeof(info) );
(uint64_t)info.WorkingSetSize;
```

Then, I used that to run a very simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>"

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t currentUsedRAM(0);

    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));
    currentUsedRAM = info.WorkingSetSize;

    const int N(1000000);
    int x[N]; //in the second run, comment this line out
    int y[N]; //in the second run, comment this line out
    //int *x = new int[N]; //in the second run UNcomment this line out
    //int *y = new int[N]; //in the second run UNcomment this line out
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 1;
        y[i] = 2;
    }

    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));
    currentUsedRAM = info.WorkingSetSize - currentUsedRAM;

    std::cout << "Current RAM used: " << currentUsedRAM << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand at all when I run the code above, the output is: `Current RAM used: 0`, while I was expecting something around 8mb since I filled two 1D `int` arrays of 1 million entries each. Now, if I re-run the code but making `x` and `y` become dinamically allocated arrays, now the output is, as expected: `Current RAM used: 8007680`.

Why is that? How to make it detect memory-usage in both cases?

Comment: I'm surprised your program even starts, because you allocate almost 8 megs of memory on the stack for the two arrays. The default stack size on Windows is usually a single MB. And with this you should also get a hint about why you don't get the expected result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is **exactly** what got my in doubt. My intuition was precisely that the function was only measuring memory allocation at the heap, not at the stack. However, because the application runs, I could not understand what was going on. So, it is just that the function only gets heap memory usage. Is there a way to calculate stack memory usage?

Comment: The compile have optimised out those two array. You can make some side-effect to prevent this: try to output the sum of their element.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler have optimised your code. If fact, for your first run, neither x or y is allocated. Considering that there is visible side effect : the return value of GetProcessMemoryInfo, this optimiszation seems kind of weird.

Anyway, you can prevent this by adding some other side effect, such as outputing the sum of each element of those two array, which will guarateen the crashing.

**The memory allocating for local objects with automatic storage duration happens [at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)**. So your code  can't measure the memory usage for any automatic sotrage duration variable in main(nor my deleted code snippet, Which I wasn't awared of). But things are different for those objects with dynamic storage duration, they are allocated per request.

---

I designed a test which involves recusion for the discussion in comment area. You can see that the memory usage increased if the program goes deeper. This is a proof to that it counts the memroy usage on stack. BTW, it isn't counting how many memory your objects need, but how many your program needs.

```
void foo(int depth, int *a, int *b, uint64_t usage) {
  if (depth >= 100)
    return ;
  int x[100], y[100];

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    x[i] = 1 + (a==nullptr?0:a[i]);
    y[i] = 2 + (b==nullptr?0:b[i]);
  }

  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
  GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));

  std::cout << "Current RAM used: " << info.WorkingSetSize - usage << "\n";

  foo(depth+1,x,y,usage);

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    sum += x[i] + y[i];

  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  uint64_t currentUsedRAM(0);
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
  GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));
  currentUsedRAM = info.WorkingSetSize;

  foo(0, nullptr, nullptr, currentUsedRAM);

  return 0;
}

/*
Current RAM used: 0
Current RAM used: 61440
Current RAM used: 65536
Current RAM used: 65536
Current RAM used: 65536
Current RAM used: 65536
Current RAM used: 69632
Current RAM used: 69632
Current RAM used: 69632
Current RAM used: 69632
Current RAM used: 69632
Current RAM used: 73728
*/
```

The system allocate 4k each time, which is the size of a page. I don't know why it comes 0, and then suddenly 61440. Explaining how windows manages the memory is very hard and is far beyond my ability, though I have confident in the 4k thing... and that it do count the memory usage for variables with automatic storage duration.

Comment: I guess that changing N does not change the Current RAM used is because the size of stack is fixed.

Comment: I don't think so. Try changing the number of iterations of your loop from 1 to how high you can get within th stack (i.e. around 250000). You will see that the amount of RAM used does not change. The RAM you are capturing has nothing to do with the created array. The array is not counted because it is all in the stack and the function, I am guessing only counts heap memory. The number you are getting for RAM usage is entirel due to the incredibly costly `std::cout` call. If you comment out everything else and only leave a `std::cout << 1 << std::endl`, you will get around same RAM usage.

Comment: (sorry, I accidentally erased the first comment while trying to edit it. But now I am confident of what I had said in it because, as you see in new comment above, I have tested it. Follow what I just said and you will see)